# Status Unavailable in net use command using psexec

Tags: sharing, psexec

We connected to remote computer using psexec. We are running .bat file which initiates scanstate.exe to scan computer files and settings to remote network location `\\server\path1`.
The scanstate error is:

```
"An error occurred processing the command line. Invalid store path; check the store parameter and/or file system permissions."
```

Scanstate is using remote disk location: `\\server\path1`

When we execute *net use* via psexec session:

```
    Status       Local     Remote                    Network
    
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Unavailable  F:        \\server\path1           Microsoft Windows Network
    Unavailable  G:        \\server\path2           Microsoft Windows Network

The command completed successfully.
```

When we run scanstate from desktop directly (not from psexec), the disks are available  and everything works.

When we try map drive via psexec session with domain admin user privileges:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net use F: \\server\path1 /user:domain\user1 Password1
System error 1312 has occurred.


A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

How to access remote network drive via psexec?

Comment: Anybody? I am still in need of this

Answer (score 1):

https://portal.nutanix.com/page/documents/kbs/details?targetId=kA07V000000LUutSAG

This is due to the below group policy.  In order to pass the credentials to map the share this policy will need to be disabled.
Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for authentication
Note: Mapping without credentials works with this policy enabled.

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
2. Go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options, under group policy editor.
3. Find the policy Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for authentication, and set it to disabled or not configured.